# Let $x, y$ and $z$ be three natural numbers such that $xyz+xy+x^{2}+yz+x+y+z=1000$. What is the value of $x+y+z$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $x, y$ and $z$ be three natural numbers such that
>   $xyz+xy+x^{2}+yz+x+y+z=1000$. What is the value of $x+y+z$?

I found this question on another platform and I have no idea how to resolve it. It is relevant to more people than just me.

I will be grateful for any attempt!

Comment: Are they any three natural numbers or three different natural numbers? Values of (1, 1, 332) fit for the first case.

Comment: On what platform did you find it? [I hope it's not some kind of open contest...]

Comment: Are you sure it's $x^2$ and not $xz$? Sloppy handwriting could lead to such mistake. And $$xyz+xy+xz+yz+x+y+z=(x+1)(y+1)(z+1) - 1$$ which makes it easy to find the equation's solutions in natural numbers.

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal, any three natural numbers

Comment: @AdamLatosiński:  you need $+1$ on the left. This will make a unique answer if $0$ is not a natural

Comment: @coffeemath, Brainly

Comment: @AdamLatosiński, I found the question in this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated, the problem does not have a single solution.  $x=1, y=1, z=332$ and $x=1,y=4,z=110$ are both solutions.  Shikhar Jaiswal found the first and I found the second by trial and error.  There may well be more.

I agree with Adam Latosiński that the problem is intended to be 
$$xyz+xy+xz+yz+x+y+z=1000$$
because one can turn that into 
$$(x+1)(y+1)(z+1)=1001$$
As $1001=7\cdot 11 \cdot 13$ we have a unique answer for $x+y+z$ of $28$ as long as we do not accept $0$ as a natural.  You need to be able to factor the expression for this to work.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much! :)